# Install-package succeeds, Update-Package always fails. Why?

Tags: nuget, nuget-package

I'm lead developer on a project where, even though we're not using .Net, we're using nuget as a packaging technology because...well...because it ticks a lot of boxes for us (i.e. packaging as a single artifact, versioning, internal nuget server for distribution). In practice we make heavy use of the [`<files>` element in our .nuspec files](https://docs.nuget.org/create/nuspec-reference#specifying-files-to-include-in-the-package) to package up reusable code artifacts and then consume wherever they are required.

In each codebase in which we consume .nupkg packages we have a Visual Studio solution (.sln file) that simply contains a packages.config file, the solution contains zero projects.
[image: solution]

This is working great except for one thing, we have one .nupkg (dh.PSP.SSE.Engine) that refuses to be updated. Each time we try and update-package it fails with:

```
Update-Package : 'dh.PSP.SSE.Engine' was not installed in any project. Update failed
```

[image: update-package fails]

install-package works just fine:

[image: install-package succeeds]

Here is dh.PSP.SSE.Engine.nuspec:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package >
  <metadata>
    <id>dh.PSP.SSE.Engine</id>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <authors>dunnhumby</authors>
    <owners>dunnhumby</owners>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <summary>Strategic Scoring Engine - Engine</summary>
    <description>Strategic Scoring Engine - Engine</description>
    <releaseNotes/>
    <copyright>Copyright 2014</copyright>
  </metadata>
  <files>
    <file src="fs\**" />
    <file src="Cronacle\**" target="Cronacle" exclude="Cronacle\Cronacle.car;Cronacle\com\**;Cronacle\META-INF\**" />
    <file src="VersionNumberStamp.txt" target="VersionNumberStamp_dh.PSP.SSE.Engine.txt" />
    <file src="packages\dh.PSP.SSE.Ape.*\*.jar" target="lib" />
    <file src="packages\dh.PSP.SSE.Chimp.*\programs\*.py" target="lib" />
  </files>
</package>
```

We are nonplussed as to why this is happening. We have a theory that the fact we're using nuget at a solution level rather than a project level might be an issue but that said, I don't think we're doing anything that nuget wasn't designed for. Also, we have many other packages (>10), all of which update just fine.

This is a bit speculative but does anyone have any suggestions as to why this isn't working or what we might be able to do to investigate further. We're at a bit of a dead end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jamie, could you add the contents of the .nuspec file, it could be a subtlety between the NuGet Solution and Project level package format, maybe it has changed recently?

Taken from https://docs.nuget.org/consume/nuget-faq

Working with Packages
What is the difference between a project-level package and a solution-level package?

> A solution-level package has to be installed only once in a solution to be available for all projects in the solution. A project-level package must be installed separately in each project where you want to use it. For solution-level packages, NuGet doesn't change anything in a project, whereas in a project-level package it does. Typically, a solution-level package installs new commands that can be called from within the Package Manager Console window.

Comment: Good call Lloyd. Done.

Comment: So that nuspec (use of \lib folder) makes your NuGet package a Project level package, not a [solution level package ](https://docs.nuget.org/create/creating-and-publishing-a-package#creating-a-solution-level-package), seeing as you have "zero projects" in the solution I would look at resolving that first, maybe you had a project once?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @lloyd-holman I figured this out. My .nupkg has a "lib" folder so Nuget Package Manager thinks its a project-level nuget package. hence it can't update it as a solution-level nuget package.